# How to add delay in JPanel

Tags: java, algorithm, timer, path-finding

I'm making a pathfinding visualizer in java and I've got everythings down i just need to add a delay so the maze doesn't get completed instantly once i run the program. I tried adding Thread.sleep but my JPanel just doesn't show up when I add it. Does it have something to do with the fact that it's a JPanel and not the usual java program?

Here's my code:

```
public void AStar(Panel maze, Node start, Node end) {
        // Init all distances with infinity

        for (Node[] node : maze.node) {
            for (Node n : node) {
                n.distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                n.rootDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                n.manhattanDistance = 2 * (Math.abs(end.col - n.col) + Math.abs(end.row - n.row));
            }
        }
        // Distance to the root itself is zero
        start.distance = 0;

        // Init queue with the root node
        queue.add(start);

        // Iterate over the priority queue until it is empty.
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if(search() == end) {
                    backtrackPath();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

```
public Node search() {
        Node curNode = queue.poll(); // Fetch next closest node
        if (curNode != endPoint && curNode != startPoint) curNode.setAsDiscovered(); // Mark as discovered

        // Iterate over unvisited neighbors
        for (Node neighbor : GetUnvisitedNeighbors(curNode)) {
            // Update root minimal distance to neighbor including manhattan distance
            neighbor.rootDistance = Math.min(neighbor.rootDistance, curNode.rootDistance + 1);
            int minDistance = Math.min(neighbor.distance, neighbor.rootDistance + neighbor.manhattanDistance);
            if (minDistance != neighbor.distance) {
                neighbor.distance = minDistance; // update mininmal distance
                neighbor.parent = curNode; // update best parent
                // Change queue priority of the neighbor since it have became closer.
                if (queue.contains(neighbor)) {
                    queue.remove(neighbor);
                    queue.add(neighbor);
                }
            }
            // Add neighbor to the queue for further visiting.
            if (!queue.contains(neighbor)) {
                queue.add(neighbor);

            }

        }
        return curNode;
    }
```

I tried using thread.sleep but using this just makes the program wait until it's repeated over and over again and THEN shows up but when the maze is completed too, it doesn't update in real time which I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237208/update-java-swing-jframe-on-every-loop/70240917#70240917)

Comment: It occurs to me, if you're not interested in "real time" feedback, you could have your "solver" generate a "history" of moves.  You could then "replay" this history in a more suitable manner, avoiding all the Swing related threading issues (or more easily within your control)